# Proper method for Dictionary installation in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I want to install English English Dictionary or English Malayalam Dictionary.is there any method for dictionary installation ?.

Answer (score 1):

Artha is a thesaurus but also contains a LOT of definitions, it can really act like a dictionary. It is based on WordNet which is a large lexical database of English nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs groups as synonyms.

Run the below command on terminal to install artha,

```
sudo apt-get install artha
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install spelling check language dictionaries by opening a terminal and entering

```
sudo apt-get install aspell aspell-en aspell-ml
```

Answer (score 0):

free Unofficial Offline version of olam English ->Malayalam Malayalam->English Malayalam-> Malayalam

[image: Install via the software center]